# Amazon s3 bucket path issue

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am new to amazons3 i want to upload a file to s3 bucket. So i am writing a code in java for that but I don't how to specify the path of the bucket. Can any one help me in that.
PLease help in finding a solution for getting the correct path of the s3 bucket.

```
public class SampleS3 {

    private static final String SUFFIX = "/";
    private static String existingBucketName = "s3-buckt path";
    private static String AccessKey = "accesskey";
    private static String SecretAccessKey = "SecretAccessKey";
    private static String keyName = "mypic.JPG";
    private static String filePath = "/home/dll files/samplefile.txt";
    private static String amazonFileUploadLocationOriginal = existingBucketName+ "/";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        executeUpload();
    }

    private static void executeUpload() {

        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey,
                SecretAccessKey);

        AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        String folderName = "testfolder";
        createFolder(existingBucketName, folderName, s3Client);
        String fileName = folderName + SUFFIX + "testvideo.mp4";
        s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(existingBucketName, fileName,
                new File(filePath))
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    }

    public static void createFolder(String bucketName, String folderName,
            AmazonS3 client) {
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(0);
        InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,
                folderName + SUFFIX, emptyContent, metadata);
        client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
    }

}
```

When I run the program i get error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: 2D45010A48E44C42), S3 Extended Request ID: c7zzSgYO8bNUh9HoOVVmAbjjtG7G6w5tQmuSIqTmgf3cGqjclTrJS3WIXvPpV7Mt
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1389)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:902)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3826)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1405)
    at com.qagate.s3.amazons3.SampleS3.createFolder(SampleS3.java:65)
    at com.qagate.s3.amazons3.SampleS3.executeUpload(SampleS3.java:45)
    at com.qagate.s3.amazons3.SampleS3.main(SampleS3.java:33)
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to know the way to use the s3-bucket path

Comment: Your bucket name has a space and I don't think that flies: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: Actually "s3-buckt path" this is not the bucket name , its "CVR-TEST"  bucket in the S3 ,but its showing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

S3 is not like a Linux file system.

Your S3 storage consists of buckets which contain objects in a completely flat space.  The concept of "folder" is artificial: an object with key "foo" lives in the same flat bucket namespace as an object with key "path/to/bar".  There is no separate step of creating a folder; you just give your object a key whose name contains separators like '/' and you can treat the buckets as having folders through some of the LIST APIs that involve common prefixes.

However, *buckets* do have to be created, once, before you can store things in them.  You have to indicate, among other things, what region should host objects which go in that bucket.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me as I was including bucket path with the bucket name instead of the key. :)

Answer (score 0):

Either the bucket name you given is incorrect or you didn't create the bucket.

You need to check out documentation about [Bucket Restriction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/BucketRestrictions.html). From the documentation

> - Bucket names must be at least 3 and no more than 63 characters long.
> - Bucket names must be a series of one or more labels. Adjacent labels    are separated by a single period (.). Bucket names can
>   contain    lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each label must
>   start and    end with a lowercase letter or a number.
> - Bucket names must not be formatted as an IP address (e.g.,
>   192.168.5.4).
> - When using virtual hosted–style buckets with SSL, the SSL wildcard    certificate only matches buckets that do not contain periods. To work
>   around this, use HTTP or write your own certificate verification logic. We recommend that you do not use periods (".") in bucket
>   names.